# Store Roles and Permissions in backend to reduce database calls

Tags: c#, .net, api, user-permissions, dot

Let's suppose we have 3 microservices, one of them is the identity server. When the user login, we create a token and get his roles and permissions after validating the credentials (obviously).

So, every time the user accesses/calls the API from the other 2 microservices, we don't want to make a database call based on the token to check whether the user has access/permission for the particular API or not. Also, we don't want to store the roles and permissions in session as there could be thousands (suppose 50000) of user login in at the same time.

Can anyone suggest a solution to reduce the database call in the **.NET backend** only?

I thought of creating a txt file by the name of token or username and storing the roles and permissions for that user and retrieving them when required. If the token expired, will delete the txt file and create a new one with the new token name.

But I think this is not the correct way to code for major projects. So, looking for good and effective use of **DOT NET features**.

Comment: Typically the roles/permissions are in the token so just validate the token (that the signature is valid) and then use the data from the token. No need to call anything anywhere to get that info. You already have it.

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a recommendation: is this a dedicated single server hosting the services on IIS? An AWS Lambda or Azure Function? A server farm? Load balancers? What have you tried? Are you prematurely optimizing something that's not a bottleneck?

Comment: Dont you have to add a User everytime you check the token? To my knowledge, you cannot store data in your API. You have to have some form of persistence and a database call is quite a bit faster than reading a textfile everytime a user requests something.
Not that you should never store any data in your api as this might be outdated when someone changes the role of a user in the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Ralf yes, we can use the token only to validate the role and permissions but there can be multiple roles and permissions for the users so we will have to create json for all the permissions and roles and then will have to check whether the token has the access for particular API. 
But if there is any other way then that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @MetroSmurf This is dedicated to a single server hosted on AWS (most probably). The second option would be Azure.

Comment: Yes there can be multiple roles/permission so write all of them into the token? Don't quite understand your problem then or what json has todo with it. Your API endpoints should know the needed permission for them on there own. So it should be a simple check on the endpoints of "only these permissions are allowed here are they in the token".  That is typically done by an Authorize Attribute added to the endpoints that takes a list of roles (and policies if needed).

Comment: @Ralf Let me try with the token approach only but just to illustrate my point, here is an example:
User 1: roles: Admin, Manager
Permissions: Admin will have Edit, Download, Add, Update, View, Delete
Manager will have Edit, Add, Update, View

User 2: Roles: Employee, Client
Permissions: Employee will have View only
The Client will have View, Download, and Request for Delete.

All these roles and role-based permissions will be stored in a Token.

Hope I am making my point clear this time. :)

But thank you all. I will try and update you.